# Read a folder on local machine using azure function c#

Tags: c#, http, azure-functions

Is it possible to read a file located on local machine path `C:\data` with an azure function trigger by http request ?

Comment: You want to access the file your local pc or the azure environment?

Comment: I want to access file from my local pc. My problem is that this function will be used to read data located in another pc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say no. The resource that you want to read data from needs to be accessible from the web. Put the files in the cloud so that the function can access them.

Comment: It's possible now atleast with a combination of HCM and SFTP, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582498/1820783.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a local file system to Azure using the [on-premises data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection).

However this supported from [Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview), but not as far as I know from Functions. You could however still use the Logic App as a bridge to your Function using the [Azure Function Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions).

You are of course free to use your own personal computer however you like, but be aware that the on-premises data gateway exposes machines on your own network directly to the internet, which in the context of a business is often considered a significant security hazard. Definitely do not do this in a business context without clearing it with IT security persons first.